# jquery slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am appending images dynamically and then loading the jQuery file for slider, but problem is iamges are appearing but slider not working.

HTML code :-

```
<div id="banner-fade">
         <ul class="bjqs" id="gallerySlider">

          </ul>
        </div>
 <script src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
  <script class="secret-source">

          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
                 animtype      : 'slide',   
                height      : 320,
                width       : 620,
                responsive  : true,
                animspeed:2000
              });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="assets/js/upcomingEventLoader.js"></script>
```

error are coming in slider.js

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null

```
  e(window).resize(function() {
      m.width=i.outerWidth(), m.ratio=m.width/r.width, m.height=r.height*m.ratio;
      o.css( {
        height: m.height, width: m.width
      }
      );
      o.children("img").css( {
        height: m.height, width: m.width
      }
      );
      s.css( {
        height: m.height, width: m.width*r.slidecount
      }
      );
      i.css( {
        height: m.height
      }
      );
      h.css( {
        height: m.height, width: m.width
      }
      );
      w(function() {
        O(!1, v.currentslide)
      }
      , 200, "some unique string")
    }
```

Error at h.css line

Comment: You can see the line number of the error in your console. Please post the corresponding codes too..

Comment: Maybe you're missing the content inside `.bjqs`? Add `<li>Lorem ipsulum</li>` and give it a try.

Comment: @Filipe  images are coming in <li> but slider not working

Comment: jQuery("#banner-fade .bjqs") perhaps? Unless this selector is specifically constructed by one of your js plugins, you can't select elements like you are. Where is var "h" defined?

Comment: @rsn  h=e('<div class="bjqs-wrapper"></div>');

Comment: What if you add that line "<div class="bjqs-wrapper"></div>" into your HTML?